# Question about removing number lines and name of journal

Tags: amsmath, document-classes, line-numbering

I want to remove number lines and also the name of journal of the top of this latex template, how can I do it?

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,amsmath,graphics}
\let\widebar\overline
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsfonts,yhmath}
\usepackage[breaklinks,colorlinks,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,
            pagecolor=black,urlcolor=black,hyperindex=false]{hyperref}
\PageIndex
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\EnableCrossrefs
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{aomart.dtx}
\end{document}
```

See https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/aomart

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide the template not in an external link. And make sure to provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). You could edit your question here and add the code directly.

Comment: The fact is that I don't know the code, if I knew then I could use %

Comment: You can't provide the code, which generates unwanted "number lines and also the name of journal of the top"? Really? Without code we can't help you.

Comment: The code is available in new link

Comment: We don't like an external link. We need compilable code starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. It will allow readers to copy-and-paste-and-compile your code and see exactly what problems you might be experiencing.

Comment: In addition, other people may come along later because they had a similar problem, and then perhaps the external link no longer works.

Comment: see https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/aomart

Comment: Don't use a journal or conference class unless you are submitting to that journal or conference. These classes are designed to be inflexible - they impose a standard style. If you're not submitting there, you won't want that inflexibility. The answer: use a more flexible, standard class.

Comment: The file you've posted is intended to produce the packages documentation. It is not a document which uses the class at all.